# App not showing in launcher

Tags: android, android-studio, nexus-5

After installing an app via the run command on Android Studio, the app launches correctly, I can see it in the applications list and account manager.
The problem is that it doesn't show up at all in the app launcher. (I have Google Launcher installed on the Nexus 5 device which I am testing on and everything was working fine before 6.0.1). 
App name is "Pumpkin".

[Here is the manifest](http://pastebin.com/s2BJBwzS)

And here's the screenshot where Pumpkin's supposed to fit.

[image: The launcher]

Comment: It'll be difficult to provide a screenshot for something that is missing. I run the app. It launches (so I guess it is installed). It shows up in applications list in the phone settings, but not in the launcher. Which means if I kill the app, I can't run it again.

Comment: Cf edit for screenshot and Manifest

Comment: What is 'Pumpkin Pro' in the above screen shot? is your app name or icon you provided is correct? check your strings.xml and <application tag in manifest

Comment: Pumpkin Pro is a different app. (Solved below anyway).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Your Intent-Filter seems to be wrong. Change to:

```
<activity
       android:name="com.pumpkin.activities.SplashScreenActivity"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="pumpkin.com" android:host="open" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: It's weird that it used to work before, then. 
Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @KarimKouznetsov hm yeah, separating the intent-filters worked for me as well, when did that change come about?

Comment: I don't quite remember now, but I recall was trying to implement deep linking for [branch.io](https://branch.io/)

Comment: I renamed my package through IntelliJ IDEA and it caused this. I'm guessing a bug in their system.

Comment: thanks a lottttt...... I was searching for solution from days....  i was defining <data android:scheme="" in both of my intent filters... which was creating the issue :)

Comment: Thank you, works. Is there any logical explanation behind this?

Answer (score 0):

Add this intent filter to your splash screen activity:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: The other attributes are for deep linking mechanics. This is not "Too much stuff".

Comment: It shouldn't be together with the launcher filter, see the other answer from @Christopher, it is better written...