# my app is not showing in the list to open txt file in android 7.1.1

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter, android-7.1-nougat

Hi i am developing an app to open txt files.When user touches a txt file on sd card my app should shown in open with list. My app is working file with other android version but phone doesn't show my app in open with list. Phone is generel mobile gm5+ .i don't know it is because of the phone or android version. here is my manifest

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ui.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />


            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />


        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: post logcat errors if any generated

Comment: no log cat generated

Comment: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34392538/app-not-showing-in-launcher

Comment: @SurendraKumar unfortunately didn't work

Comment: So try to reset app preferences. There might be an app set as default launch app for text files. Go to "Settings->Apps-> Menu(3 dots on top right) -> Reset App Preferences".

Comment: tried it but didnt work. Maybe its the device causing this ?

Comment: Then to make sure run the same app on some other device with same OS version. If that works, device is the culprit.

Comment: @SurendraKumar same device same version result is the same :(

Comment: hey...Please try with some other device. The issue might be specific to GM device. Try with some mainstream vendors like Samsung or HTC.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have permission of

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Try something like this

```
<activity 
    android:name=".ui.SplashActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:scheme="file" />       
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

`<data android:scheme="file" />` => this define that the file must be local, not from http or else

`<data android:mimeType="*/*" />` => match any mime type (to be specific use mimeType="text/plain")

`<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />` => this is where you specify what extension you want to match

**intent-filter can contain multiple actions** as per need also two intent-filter should also need to work

Hope this help

Comment: same code just replace mimeType="text/plain"  ? just try

Comment: try this if not work i have one anther idea ..let me know first

Answer (score 0):

You must use content as well:

```
    <data android:scheme="content"
          android:mimeType="text/*" />
```

You can also use pathpattern here or specify other mimeTypes